# What parameter dictates the analog output speed for this board?

Tags: analog, datasheet, board

I plan to use [this](http://www.testdynamics.co.za/Product/PDF/PXIe6341.pdf) I/O Device for a project where the the analog output should be able to settle to a value for a 100 kHz moving point scan device. Meaning that between point A and point B the analog output of the board should change fast enough.

I need to increase the analog output of this board from -2.5 V to +2.5 V with 5 mV step increase accurate enough.

The analog output step change should follow the max scan rate which is 100 kHz. Meaning that the analog output for each successive step should change/settle fast and accuarte enough in 1/100 kHz = 0.01 ms.

From the data sheet how can we conclude whether the analog output is capable of such change?

Comment: how many data points are in one cycle of 100 kHz?

Comment: Between 1000 to 2000 points.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to figure out the bandwidth of the system?

Comment: Im not sure about that definition(maybe its the correct one). What I want is how quick can the DAC output settle lets say from 5mV to 10mV.

Comment: Is this controlling a galvanometer scanner?

Comment: @user1850479  Yes exactly. But in my case one scan corresponds one point  on the pane. So the galvo should move in sync with the scan. And the DAC will control  galvo steps. galvo scanner is here https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=GVS112

Comment: @GNZ  Bandwidth of that galvo controller is 1 KHz, so Nyquist is 2 KHz for your system.  However, I strongly recommend 100 KHz, since you want to synchronize all of your clocks and there is no harm to oversampling.  I'll type up a detailed answer.

Comment: @Thanks. And how did you derive 1kHz BW? What does that mean in teems of its movement?

Answer (score 1):

> The analog output step change should follow the max scan rate which is 100 kHz. Meaning that the analog output for each successive step should change/settle fast and accuarte enough in 1/100 kHz = 0.01 ms.

This is not the correct way to think about your problem.  What you are really doing is providing an analog signal, which is continuously varying from -2.5 to +2.5v.  This signal is then being tracked by a control loop, which is measuring the position of the mirror and comparing to the position indicated by your control voltage. When the error gets larger, it pushes the mirror harder, and after a delay for the mirror to accelerate, hopefully the mirror converges to the indicated position, bringing the error down to zero.

Since the control loop is continuously looking at the signal voltage, there is no need to "settle".  The control loop will just as effectively compare to a signal that is changing as one that is constant.  Further, since the mirror you are driving has a lot of inertia (step time of 400 µs), while your point time is much shorter (10 µs) you actually will have the mirror moving at constant velocity while imaging.   Thus your drive waveform will be ramp that moves continuously from -2.5 to +2.5v and then reverses.  Thus, nothing will ever "settle" until you turn it off.

If you look at the datasheet, they give a maximum bandwidth of 1 KHz for a 0.2 degree scan, and a step response of 400 µs (assuming 90-10% that is a 3dB bandwidth of 875 Hz).  Thus, your Nyquist rate is about 2 KHz, or maybe a little faster depending on how fast you think the control loop's bandwidth rolls off.

Since the scanner is very, very slow relative to your pixel rate (which is normal for laser scanning), no one ever sets the sampling rate according to Nyquist for a galvanometer.  Instead, the scanner is always oversampled, and typically in applications where you have discrete A-scans, usually you run it at the A-scan rate.  The normal way this is done is to take A-scan trigger (or whatever is happening at 100 KHz) and feed that to the PFI pins on your X-series DAQ.  Then route the PFI pin to the DAC clock, and load up your fast and slow axis waveforms.  You'll vastly oversample them, but it makes synchronization so much easier if your scanners move synchronously with the A-scan rate.

> What does that [bandwidth] mean in teems of its movement?

It is essentially how fast a waveform can change while the mirror remains able to track it.  Another way to think of it is that at 1 KHz, you would be able to move the mirror through a more or less sinusoidal trajectory with a deflection of 0.2 degrees at 1 KHz.  Alternatively, if you tell the mirror to move very slightly in either direction, it'll take about 400 us to do that.  Since you have a big mirror, it is pretty slow, and you may have some issues with your chosen 100 KHz and 1000 points per line (thus 100 lines per second).  You'll definitely want to do triangle (bidirectional) scans so that you only have to do 50 complete cycles per second.  Even then you may have more nonlinearity at the start/stop of each line than you want.

Comment: Im not gonna run galvo in continuous sweep. The USB DAQ board will step the galvo for each line scan clock as you described. But this sync trigger is for line scan of a spectrometer which is same with galvo step in my case. Similar setup here https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9229119 So isnt the 100kHz clock too fast for the galvo? Can galvo settle that quick when the DAC increases 5mV  each step? Another thing is are you saying better to have more than one A scans per point? But how to index which A scan belongs what point?

Comment: I mean should the galvo clock beslower than the line scan clock? Remember in my case line scan is in z direction when the laser is still at a single point

Comment: @GNZ Could you edit your question to include your exact scan parameters (fast axis scan rate, slow axis scan rate, points per fast axis line)?   It would be a lot more simple to answer your questions if I wasn't guessing what you were trying to do.

Comment: I can later but need to go now. Its a bit complicated topic to explain all details. My question was how fast DAC can settle basically. Thanks so far

Comment: @GNZ DACs settle orders of magnitude faster than moving mirrors, so for your purposes you can assume infinitely fast electronic settling.